# Symfony2: Functional testing is failing during Fixtures load

Tags: php, symfony, testing, phpunit, functional-testing

I'm working in some functional testing for a bundle and I'm having some issues. This is the content of `LoadFeeData.php`:

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $fee = new Fee();
        $fee->setName("Comision-" . uniqid());
        $fee->setDescription($this->generateRandomString());
        $fee->setHoldback(1);
        $manager->persist($fee);
        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

And this is what I do in my test:

```
public function setUp() {
    static::$kernel = static::createKernel();
    static::$kernel->boot();
    $this->em = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();

    $loader = new Loader();
    $loader->addFixture(new LoadFeeData());

    $purger = new ORMPurger();
    $executor = new ORMExecutor($this->em, $purger);
    $executor->execute($loader->getFixtures());
}
```

But any time I try the command:

```
 phpunit -c app/ src/Company/ApprovalBundle/Tests/Controller/CommissionCompanyControllerTest.php
```

I  get this error:

> 1)
>   Company\ApprovalBundle\Tests\Controller\CommissionCompanyControllerTest::testmodifyCommissionAction
>   Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException: An exception occurred while executing
>   'DELETE FROM ext_translations':
>
> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'kraken.ext_translations' doesn't exist

Where is the error?

Comment: did you run "app/console doctrine:schema:update -- force" command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @tomas-tibensky suggestions I made some changes to my code and now fixtures are loaded as I want (I need to learn now how to delete it after test runs) but anyway here is the solution, since DB isn't updated then your need to run the command `doctrine:schema:update --force` to update DB schema and  then load the fixtures:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase,
    Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Loader,
    Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\ORMExecutor,
    Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\ORMPurger,
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application,
    Symfony\Component\Console\Input\StringInput
    Company\ApprovalBundle\Entity\CompanyHasWtax,
    Company\RegisterCompanyBundle\Entity\Company,
    Company\ApprovalBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadFeeData;

class CommissionCompanyControllerTest extends WebTestCase {

    private $em;
    protected static $application;

    public function setUp() {
        static::$kernel = static::createKernel();
        static::$kernel->boot();
        $this->em = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();

        self::runCommand('doctrine:schema:update --force');

        $loader = new Loader();
        $loader->addFixture(new LoadFeeData());

        $purger = new ORMPurger();
        $executor = new ORMExecutor($this->em, $purger);
        $executor->execute($loader->getFixtures());
    }

    protected static function runCommand($command) {
        $command = sprintf('%s --quiet', $command);

        return self::getApplication()->run(new StringInput($command));
    }

    protected static function getApplication() {
        if (null === self::$application) {
            $client = static::createClient();

            self::$application = new Application($client->getKernel());
            self::$application->setAutoExit(false);
        }

        return self::$application;
    }
}
```